# While a program is running, can you free some RAM by transferring to disk w/o using Export?

Tags: performance-tuning

While my program is running, 100's of images are being calculated. I noticed that physical memory (PM) fills up at about 500 images, and then I see the resource monitor drop the PM back to about 50% and the program continues to run.  I would like to force that transition multiple times, and I assume that is performing a data transfer to the disk.  Is there a way to do this without using Export?  I'm in Win 10 with an i7 and 32G.  My disk is solid state.

Comment: If you do not need all images at the same time, then why loading them in the first place? Simply load them in chunks. And what is so bad about `Export`?

Comment: I'm headed with all the images into Manipulate.  Manipulate is glitchy with stalls, notebook formatting messages, and crashes.  I was thinking Manipulate might run better if more RAM was free before it executed.

Comment: If you want `Manipulate` to use those images quickly and responsively, they're going to have to be in RAM anyways. It sounds to me like the issues you're having are likely to be being caused by the disk swap rather than solved by it. If you have numerous related static images, perhaps you should consider exporting them all and combining them as a movie externally?

Comment: Here's a way to update data (`yy`) asynchronously, while leaving the `Manipulate` responsive. The button could call a function that calls `Import` instead of `incY[]`, does error checking, etc. You could set a flag when the update is complete to use as a signal to the user that the image has been loaded. -- `yy = 0;
incY[] := (Pause[6]; ++yy);
ff[xx_] := xx + yy;

Manipulate[
 ff[x],
 {x, 0, 1},
 Dynamic@Button["Increase y", incY[], Method -> "Queued"]
 ]`

Comment: I am now trying mp4 export in multiple clips, however Adobe Rush has been compressing too much so I am told I have to come up to speed on Adobe Premier Pro.